# search a string in another file and replace it with another string in node js

Tags: regex, angularjs, node.js, replace

I have searched enough for this matter and found most of the answers for java same problem but for me the problem arise in a node js program.

I want to search for,

```
.made-easy-theme{
        color:black;
    }
```

in a css file and replace its 'black' with another color which I recieve from the client side of the program. Here is what I have tried, I have tried 3 ways, but none of them are working.
First concept I have tried is,

```
var main = 'temp/' + userId + '/templates/' + appId + '/css/main.css';

 var color = req.body.color;
 function replaceThemecolor(color) {

        fs.readFile(main, 'utf-8',
            function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err)
                }
                else {
                    var str = '.made-easy-theme{color:black;}';
                    if (str.search("black") != -1) {

                        var result = data.replace(/black/g, themecolor.color);

                        fs.writeFile(mainCss, result, 'utf-8', function (err) {
                            if (err) return console.log(err);
                        });
                    }
                        console.log(result);
                    }

                });    
    }
});
```

The second concept I have tried is,

```
 fs.readFile(main, 'utf-8',
            function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err)
                }
                else { 
                var ex = '.made-easy-theme{color:black;}'.includes('black');

                if (ex == true) {
                    var result = data.replace(/black/g, color);

                    fs.writeFile(main, result, 'utf-8', function (err) {
                        if (err) return console.log(err);
                    });
                    console.log(result);
                }


            }
```

The third concept I have tried is,

```
else if (data.indexOf('.made-easy-theme{color:black;}') > 0) {
                    console.log(data);

                    var result = data.replace('black', themecolor.color);

                    fs.writeFile(mainCss, result, 'utf-8', function (err) {
                        if (err) return console.log(err);
                    });
                };
```

Noone of these are  working for me, please help to resolve this problem

Comment: In my opinion, manipulating the CSS file directly is rather clunky. I'd prefer writing the rule into a custom css file, and load it later to override the rules that occur earlier. I don't know if there is a better way to do this, though.

Comment: There should be a way to do it in the way I have mentioned above, in my opinion I think there is some mistake in my code which I can't notify

Comment: It's possible, but I don't recommend you to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer

```
function replaceThemecolor(color) {

        fs.readFile(main, 'utf-8',
            function (err, data) {
                var searchStr = ".made-easy-theme{color:black}";

                    var result = searchStr.replace(new RegExp('black', ''), color);
                    fs.writeFile(main, result, 'utf-8', function (err) {

                        if (err) return console.log(err);
                    });
            });

    }
```

but the problem is that it clears the full content of the css file and replace only the

```
.made-easy-theme{
        color:black;
    }
```

the other content which was in the css file is erased. I want to keep them  and replce what I want to replace

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it, although not the best way. This code is coupled, makes bad use of string concatenation, doesn't do enough error checking and should probably use a file stream. But it will give you an idea.

Plus, it's just a dangerous thing to do.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var infile = 'test.css';
var outfile = 'temp.css';
var flag = false;
var color = 'green';
var out = '';

fs.open(infile, 'r', function(err, fd){
    changeLine(fd);
});


function changeLine(fd){
    var buf = new Buffer(1024);
    buf.fill(0);

    fs.read(fd, buf, 0, 1024, null, function(err, bytesRead, buffer){
        if(bytesRead === 0){
            writeCSS(out);
            return;
        }
        var str = buffer.toString('utf8', 0, bytesRead);
        if(/made-easy-theme/.exec(str)){
            flag = true;
        }
        if (/color:/.exec(str) && flag){
            str = str.replace('black', color);
            flag = false;
        }
        out += str;
        changeLine(fd);
    });    
}

function writeCSS(str){
    fs.writeFile(outfile, str, function(err, written, buffer){
        fs.rename(outfile, infile);
    }); 
}
```